What search filter value use to find hexadecimal indexed events logs?
I am trying to retrieve logs per topic, but I am having trouble retrieving the values.
I have the following event defined in the SC:
event Log(
    uint256 indexed dHash,
    uint256 timestamp
);

function shot(uint256 _dHash) public {
    emit Log(_dHash, block.timestamp);
}

I load the transaction data to call the function and fire an event. I enter a hexadecimal value with the following structure:
0x1a44607ab09f67bb5a6ebbca0e2e6db0aab9a84832b3b144cd5ead467d5136a2

I get the following response event in remix:
{
    "from": "0x1c91347f2A14528cR62453XXXd9Aa907C662b4bD",
    "topic": "0xb9bee24722735b5e32a17623d1f72d4cf51dc496c802c23a327388b87dde778b",
    "event": "Log",
    "args": {
        "0": "11880945538933180349093306819251927116173748391240667473553576525133153121954",
        "1": "1715340607",
        "dHash": "11880945538933180349093306819251927116173748391240667473553576525133153121954",
        "timestamp": "1715340607"
    }
}

And now I try to retrieve it but I collect zero logs if I set a filter i dont get anything and if I remove the filter I get the transactions.How should I set the filter values since I enter the value 0x1a44607ab09f67bb5a6ebbca0e2e6db0aab9a84832b3b144cd5ead467d5136a2 but in the logs response it changes the unit and sets me the value 11880945538933180349093306819251927116173748391240667473553576525133153121954?
const events = await smartContract.getPastEvents('Log', {
    filter: {dHash: 0x1a44607ab09f67bb2a6ebbca0e2e6db0aab9a84832b3b144cd5ead467d5136a2},
    //filter: {dHash: 11880945538933180349093306819251927116173748391240667473553576525133153121954},
    //filter: {dHash: "11880945538933180349093306819251927116173748391240667473553576525133153121954"},
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: 'latest'
});

console.log(events);


I finally I resolve the problem, adding an n at dHash value end. In the Javascript side. I thougth that solidity works with BigNumbers so we need to add an n.
